# There is no extension able to load the configuration for "UserBundle\Entity\User"

Tags: php, symfony, configuration

I have this custom User class:

```
namespace UserBundle\Entity;


use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // your own logic
    }
    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $email = is_null($email) ? '' : $email;
        parent::setEmail($email);
        $this->setUsername($email);

        return $this;
    }
}
```

I have also this validation.yml that is included in the configuration file:

```
UserBundle\Entity\User:
    properties:
    # Your custom fields in your user entity, here is an example with FirstName
        firstName:
            - NotBlank:
                message: acme_user.first_name.blank
                groups: [ "AcmeProfile" ]
            - Length:
                min: 2
                minMessage: acme_user.first_name.short
                max: 255
                maxMessage: acme_user.first_name.long
                groups: [ "AcmeProfile" ]



# Note: We still want to validate the email
# See FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/validation/orm.xml to understand
# the UniqueEntity constraint that was originally applied to both
# username and email fields
#
# As you can see, we are only applying the UniqueEntity constraint to
# the email field and not the username field.
FOS\UserBundle\Model\User:
    constraints:
        - Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity:
             fields: email
             errorPath: email
             message: fos_user.email.already_used
             groups: [ "AcmeRegistration", "AcmeProfile" ]

    properties:
        email:
            - NotBlank:
                message: fos_user.email.blank
                groups: [ "AcmeRegistration", "AcmeProfile" ]
            - Length:
                min: 2
                minMessage: fos_user.email.short
                max: 255
                maxMessage: fos_user.email.long
                groups: [ "AcmeRegistration", "ResetPassword" ]
            - Email:
                message: fos_user.email.invalid
                groups: [ "AcmeRegistration", "AcmeProfile" ]
        plainPassword:
            - NotBlank:
                message: fos_user.password.blank
                groups: [ "AcmeRegistration", "ResetPassword", "ChangePassword" ]
            - Length:
                min: 2
                max: 4096
                minMessage: fos_user.password.short
                groups: [ "AcmeRegistration", "AcmeProfile", "ResetPassword", "ChangePassword"]

FOS\UserBundle\Model\Group:
    properties:
        name:
            - NotBlank:
                message: fos_user.group.blank
                groups: [ "AcmeRegistration" ]
            - Length:
                min: 2
                minMessage: fos_user.group.short
                max: 255
                maxMessage: fos_user.group.long
                groups: [ "AcmeRegistration" ]

FOS\UserBundle\Propel\User:
    properties:
        email:
            - NotBlank:
                message: fos_user.email.blank
                groups: [ "AcmeRegistration", "AcmeProfile" ]
            - Length:
                min: 2
                minMessage: fos_user.email.short
                max: 255
                maxMessage: fos_user.email.long
                groups: [ "AcmeRegistration", "ResetPassword" ]
            - Email:
                message: fos_user.email.invalid
                groups: [ "AcmeRegistration", "AcmeProfile" ]

        plainPassword:
            - NotBlank:
                message: fos_user.password.blank
                groups: [ "AcmeRegistration", "ResetPassword", "ChangePassword" ]
            - Length:
                min: 2
                max: 4096
                minMessage: fos_user.password.short
                groups: [ "AcmeRegistration", "AcmeProfile", "ResetPassword", "ChangePassword"]


FOS\UserBundle\Propel\Group:
    properties:
        name:
            - NotBlank:
                message: fos_user.group.blank
                groups: [ "AcmeRegistration" ]
            - Length:
                min: 2
                minMessage: fos_user.group.short
                max: 255
                maxMessage: fos_user.group.long
                groups: [ "AcmeRegistration" ]
```

The config fie looks like:

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: services.yml }
    - { resource: config2.yml }
    - { resource: validation2.yml }
# Put parameters here that don't need to change on each machine where the app is deployed
# http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#application-related-configuration
parameters:
    locale: en

framework:
    #esi:             ~
    translator:      { fallbacks: ["%locale%"] }
    secret:          "%secret%"
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
        strict_requirements: ~
    form:            ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
    #serializer:      { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
    default_locale:  "%locale%"
    trusted_hosts:   ~
    trusted_proxies: ~
    session:
        # handler_id set to null will use default session handler from php.ini
        handler_id:  ~
    fragments:       ~
    http_method_override: true

# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
    strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"

# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   pdo_mysql
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver:
        #   1. add the path in parameters.yml
        #     e.g. database_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3"
        #   2. Uncomment database_path in parameters.yml.dist
        #   3. Uncomment next line:
        #     path:     "%database_path%"

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true

# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: "%mailer_transport%"
    host:      "%mailer_host%"
    username:  "%mailer_user%"
    password:  "%mailer_password%"
    spool:     { type: memory }

fos_user:
    db_driver: orm
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: UserBundle\Entity\User
    registration:
        form:
            type: acme_user_registration
            validation_groups: [AcmeRegistration]
    profile:
        form:
            type: acme_user_profile
            validation_groups: [AcmeProfile]
    registration:
            confirmation:
                enabled: true
    resetting:
            email:
                from_email:
                    address:        test@example.com
                    sender_name:    Demo Resetting
```

When I try to open the login page and when I try to update the database I receive an error message:

> There is no extension able to load the configuration for
>   "UserBundle\Entity\User" (in
>   C:\Apache24\htdocs\fos\app/config\validation2.yml). Looked for
>   namespace "UserBundle\Entity\User", found "framework", "security",
>   "twig", "monolog", "swiftmailer", "doctrine",
>   "sensio_framework_extra", "fos_user", "debug", "web_profiler",
>   "sensio_distribution" in
>   C:\Apache24\htdocs\fos\app/config\validation2.yml (which is being
>   imported from "C:\Apache24\htdocs\fos\app/config\config.yml").

Comment: Is your bundle declared in AppKernel ? Does your bundle declare FOSUB as its parent ?

Comment: Yes, it's declared in AppKernel and yes, declares fosub as its parent.

Comment: Found [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13741632/there-is-no-extension-able-to-load-the-configuration-for-facebookbundle-symfon) on SO, hope it can help

Comment: My structure is more complicated.

Comment: I also found to other answers that may be related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16122641/symfony2-there-is-no-extension-able-to-load-the-configuration-for, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36049362/there-is-no-extension-able-to-load-the-configuration