# There is no extension able to load the configuration service.yml

Tags: symfony, symfony1

I create event lister of login but i have probleme in configuration services.yml

code LoginListener:

```
<?php

    namespace Enso\UserBundle\EventListener;

    use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Event\InteractiveLoginEvent;
    use Symfony\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry as Doctrine;

    class LoginListener
    {
      protected $doctrine;

      public function __construct(Doctrine $doctrine)
      {
        $this->doctrine = $doctrine;
      }

      public function onLogin(InteractiveLoginEvent $event)
      {
        $user = $event->getAuthenticationToken()->getUser();

        if($user)
        {
          setNbrelog() = getNbrelog()+1;

        }
      }
    }
```

code services.yml:

```
dbla_user.login_listener:
    class: Enso\UserBundle\EventListener\LoginListener
    arguments: [@doctrine]
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: security.interactive_login, method: onLogin }
```

this probleme:

[image]

help me please and thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Symfony2: There is no extension able to load the configuration for](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16122641/symfony2-there-is-no-extension-able-to-load-the-configuration-for)

Answer (score 0):

This is a YML formatting error. In your `services.yml` you have a wrong indentation and the item `dbla_user.login_listener` is interpreted as a parent item. Notice the difference:

```
services:
  ...
  ...
  dbla_user.login_listener:
```

versus

```
services:
  ...
  ...
dbla_user.login_listener:
```